# JAVASCRIPT: dynamically load manifest.json

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, json, manifest

whilst programming for HTML I stumbled on manifest.json files, for native ***Chrome/Android*** applications, but I can not load the manifest, situated at: "/manifest.json"; I used this jQuery code to add the *link* to the *head* tag.

```
$('head').append('<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">');
```

But it adds it to the *head* of the document, but it doesn't read the manifest; it just says: "No manifest found".

Can anyone help me with this???

Answer (score 0):

you have to run the jQuery command before DOM ready

Like this

**Type 1:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('head').append('<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">');
})
```

**Type 2:** 
Use [$.getJSON](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp)

```
    $.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

---

**Script Loaded  in jQuery**:-

In this below example i didn't include bootstrap in html but i included in

`$(window).load()` It works.

```js
$(window).load(function(){

$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**No Script**

```html
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work; it still does not recognize that a manifest has been loaded.